# losing MongoDB date resolution when filtering results. Node.js/Loopback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, loopbackjs

```
function(){
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var twentyFourHours = 24*60*60*1000;
  var limit = currentDate - twentyFourHours;

  aModel.find({where:{property:something, timeStamp:{gt:limit}}},function(err,models){
    models.forEach(function(oneModel){
      console.log(oneModel.timeStamp);
      //Tue Apr 05 2016 19:48:03 GMT+0000 (UTC)
      //no ms resolution
    });
  }
}
```

Within MongoDB itself the SAME model property reads: `2016-04-05T19:48:02.314Z`  How do I avoid this lost date resolution or keep the formatting the same?

Thanks.

Comment: try date.toISOString()

Comment: @NickD I could kiss you on the mouth mein freund

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are getting a JavaScript Date object out of your database,
you must call:

```
date.toISOString();
```

to get the full date string.

[Documentation for the JS Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)